# How can I retrieve all employees whose age will be 21 in a month's time?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have an employee table with columns:

```
Id, Name, Birthdate
```

I am trying to write SQL query to retrieve all employees who will be 21 in a month's time, and another query to retrieve all employees who are currently 21.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to know employees **at least** 21 years old, not **exactly** 21 years old.

For one month from now:

`WHERE BIRTHDATEField <= DATEADD(year, -21, DATEADD(month, 1 Getdate())`

Remove the last `Dateadd` to use today.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
SELECT Name FROM Table 
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, Birthdate, DATEADD(MONTH,1,GETDATE())) >= 21
```

and

```
SELECT Name FROM Table 
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, Birthdate, GETDATE()) >= 21
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from employee e
where e.Birthdate = DATEADD(Year, -21, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()))
```